# 3 Years Old boy leaking or wetting Pants

Tags: toddler, urine

I have 3 years old son which we have trained him to go to restroom or inform parents when he needs to Pee. It worked wonderfully in the summer,spring and fall. However the problem arises when winter starts and temperatures falls below Zero Degree Celsius.

Most frequently he is peeing in his pants. At the time of peeing he is completely consciousness.

I know in the winter we feel less active and lethargic. Does this impacted him to identify peeing sensation and control it before release.

Are there any methods or approaches to help him sense earlier and inform parents or go to the rest room?

Answer (score 1):

My best advice is to put him on a toilet schedule of taking him to the toilet every sixty - ninety minutes during the day regardless of whether he wants to do or not. This will likely bother him enough to take back control of his using the facilities on his own. Do not be mad. You just explain that because he is wetting or soiling his pants, you think he needs more help. If you get mad, it makes the entire problem into a PROBLEM. Be positive and friendly; we do not want children holding their urine or feces. It is very bad for their health. 3 years is still very much in the 'normal' zone of toilet training. Try not to be discouraged. I think that the extra 'help' will encourage him to be more independent without causing any troubles. The once an hour/hour and a half stops at bedtime and he will wear his diaper at night, if that is what he is used to. Diapers are made for this. We do not want him afraid to use a diaper!